# pandas read_excel that creates index even when index_col=none

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read an excel file into a data frame and I want set the index later, so I don't want pandas to use column 0 for the index values.

By default (`index_col=None`), it shouldn't use column 0 of my data for the index.

How can i solve this please?

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'Indicators.xls', Header = True, index_col=None)
```

[Input file excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZm50.png)

The output that im getting [Output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUp7r.png)

Comment: could you plz show the traceback

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `header=None` here! (default is 0). Hope this helps!

Edit: Link to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Not yet .. Thank you @mochsner i have edited my post